# Mercurial , writing hooks using a .NET api

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, mercurial

Hi I am looking for examples of how to write Mercurial hooks in a .NET language, including how to setup .hg/hgr

I have used the "Mercurial.Net" Api, but the information in the Windows environment variables is a bit limited and returning error messages on the standard error channel does not appear to work. I guess I am doing something wrong.

I am using .Net for a number of reasons , one being to link up with other systems using WFC

Comment: Hi, if you're talking about my open source project, http://mercurialnet.codeplex.com, I'd be happy to help, if I can. Unfortunately I'm away at a conference until later today (about 12 hours) so I won't have access to my computer until then. Unfortunately I haven't created any hooks yet so I need to read up on how to do that. If necessary, I can add changes to the library to make it easier to make hooks.

Comment: Hi. Work has begun on implementing hook support in Mercurial.Net, until I'm done I won't post a real "answer" here on SO, but you can follow the work on https://lassevk.kilnhg.com/Repo/MercurialNet/dev/hooks and weigh in on http://mercurialnet.codeplex.com/discussions/261283

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT The new version of Mercurial.Net makes writing hooks easier, see see http://mercurialnet.codeplex.com/discussions/261283

1. Create a "Windows Application" project (eg MyHook).
2. Add a reference to "Mercurial.Net" (you can use NuGet to make it easier http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Mercurial.Net).
3. In your main method, do whatever processing you want (eg retrieve the log and then the info on the last commit - see http://mercurialnet.codeplex.com/discussions/261283 for examples). You can add a `MessageBox.Show(message)` to check that the hook is indeed executed.
4. Compile your project.
5. Add the hook to your .hg/hgrc file (below is an example of a hook that will be executed after each commit, see https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Hook for more info, http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html for even more info):

   ```
   [hooks]
   commit.hook1 = "C:\path to file\MyHook.exe"
   ```

The next time you commit your hook should be executed.

Check http://docs.vkarlsen.no/Mercurial.Net/ to learn about the classes of Mercurial.Net.